# Parse a particular string from a given string

Tags: java, regex

**Your last 15Sec have been charged from Free minutes onnet ,left 1Hr 11Min 45Sec**

I want to parse this respose. Here i want to get values corresponding to hours, minutes and seconds seperately(e.g. it should return 1 for hour, 11 for minutes and 45 for seconds).

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think it would be better if you just use the text from the image instead of adding this huge image.

Comment: I tried it seperately like first pattern was on behalf of Hr and corresponding to that i got mather.group() and then for Min as well as for Sec but it seems this process is lenthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(\d+)Hr (\d+)Min (\d+)Sec/
```

---

How to use this pattern in Java:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)Hr (\\d+)Min (\\d+)Sec");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Your last 15Sec have been charged from Free minutes onnet ,left 1Hr 11Min 45Sec");

if(matcher.find()) {
    String hours = matcher.group(1);
    String minutes = matcher.group(2);
    String seconds = matcher.group(3);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it returns 1Hr 11Min 45Sec. For this again it needed to apply regex to get values corresponding to Hr, Min and Sec

Comment: @AnilKumar Sounds like you're looking at group 0, as it will contain the full matched string. Check my updated answer to see how to use the pattern in Java.